# Given a typed object literal, how do I ensure another object literal has all of the keys from the previous object?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have these two object literals that are supposed to have the same keys, but different values.
Values in `obj_1` must be of type `FooClass`. Values in `obj_2` must be of type `string | null`.

```
const obj_1: Record<string, FooClass> = {
  key_1: fooObj1,
  key_2: fooObj2,
  ket_3: fooObj3,
}

// Unclear what type to set for obj_2
const obj_2 = {
  key_1: "fooKey1",
  key_2: null,
  k4: "fooKey4"
}
```

##### Question

**How do I type `obj_2` such that I get type errors** because:

1. `key_3` is present in `obj_1` but missing in `obj_2` i.e. missing key
2. `k4` is present in `obj_2` but not present in `obj_1` i.e. extraneous key

##### Solutions I have considered

1. *String Enum* -- I can create a *String Enum* to list out all the keys, and then use that to type both `obj_1` and `obj_2`. However, I expect the keyset to be some 30+ keys and I would like to avoid writing them three times.
2. *Inferred Type* -- I can remove the type for `obj_1`, then I can set the type for `obj_2` using `keyof typeof obj_1`, which will give a type that is the union of the key literals. This will allow me to satisfy *condition 2*, but not *condition 1*. I can use this option if there is another way to ensure that values of `obj_1` are of type `FooClass`.

Comment: You want `satisfies` instead of a type annotation.  On mobile now but if this isn’t answered or pointed at a duplicate when I get back to a real computer I’ll do so

Comment: Okay I'm back; does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wE8K3W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (or probably close this as a duplicate); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This does exactly what I need. I was not aware of the `satisfies` operator. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I linked several previous questions here; good luck!